# Objective C - Accessing files in zip without extracting zip

Tags: objective-c, memory, zip

I'm looking for a way to access files within a zip file without extracting the whole file. All the zip solutions I find on the internet seems to extract the whole zip. Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has an objective-c lib based on minizip. http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/
Supports unzip of individual files

EDIT: the project has moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip)

Answer (score 2):

The [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) library source distribution comes with a 'contrib' directory. In it, you'll find a library called 'minizip' (same license as zlib itself), which has APIs for creating (zip.h) and navigating/extracting (unzip.h) ZIP files. Despite the filename, there are functions in unzip.h which let you list or search for files within the zip file without extracting it.

Answer (score 1):

If the zip is up on the internet you can have a look at `pinch` which will let you extract individual files from the zip without downloading the whole file.

https://github.com/epatel/pinch-objc

Maybe you can use it as a base to extract individual files from a local zip archive.