# How do I read image files directly from a zip without extracting to disk?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

What I want to do is assign images to ui elements at runtime (think Winamp style) but I have no idea how to go about reading from a zip without storing to disk. Or how to assign each image to a ui element

I'm working on a mac with cocoa and objective c

Comment: Just a quick Note. Im using osx and objective c as per the tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - Accessing files in zip without extracting zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498900/objective-c-accessing-files-in-zip-without-extracting-zip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [objective-c zip (iOS/Mac zlib wrapper)](http://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip)

Then you can do:

```
ZipFile *unzipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:@"test.zip" mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];
[unzipFile goToFirstFileInZip];

ZipReadStream *read= [unzipFile readCurrentFileInZip];
NSMutableData *data= [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:256];
int bytesRead= [read readDataWithBuffer:data];

[read finishedReading];
```

Comment: Many thanks. Will this Add much to the programs memory footprint? And would it be possible to generate a plist or dictionary per file?

Comment: What exactly do you do? Do you only zip one plist file? The footprint with libz is small unless you compress uncompress large files.

Comment: Going to be working on a theme engine for an app and want to use zip files with a custom extension for loading in the images. I need each image in the zip to be applied to a ui element. I figured a plist or dictionary would work. Is there an easier way?

Comment: @Swati it's now available here: https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip

Answer (score 1):

The [zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) version:

```
ZZArchive* archive = [ZZArchive archiveWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"test.zip"]];
NSData* data = [archive.entries[0] newDataWithError:nil];
```

Or if you're looking for a particular entry:

```
ZZArchive* archive = [ZZArchive archiveWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"test.zip"]];
NSData* data = nil;
for (ZZArchiveEntry* entry in archive.entries)
  if ([entry.fileName isEqualToString:@"test.txt"])
  {
    data = [entry newDataWithError:nil];
    break;
  }
```

Scanning for files like this is pretty much optimal. The scan only uses the zip central directory and doesn't actually extract the data until `-[entry newDataWithError:]`.