# Is it possible to read epub file without unzipping in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, epub

I have an epub file saved with me in documents directory.
Can anybody suggest me a way to read the data and chapters without unzipping the file.

I know its possible in Android so there must be a way out for apple too.

Can anybody throw some light on this.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the link which helped me :

https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip

Thanks to  : Ben Swanson & Petesh :)

Answer (score 2):

An .epub file is just a .zip file. It contains a few directory files in XML format and the actual book content is usually XHTML.

As a walk around, try to access the `META-INF/container.xml`, if you did it, you can read it without any unzipping

More info: [Epub Format Construction Guide](http://www.hxa.name/articles/content/epub-guide_hxa7241_2007.html)

Comment: how to access the container file is the issue.

Comment: You want [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230561/how-do-i-read-image-files-directly-from-a-zip-without-extracting-to-disk)

Comment: link no longer exists.....can anyone provide the wrapper